# XPath problem with skipping the element / joining matches

Tags: xpath

This is the data:

```
<p>
<span class="z">XXX</span><br/>
123456<br/>
78910</p>
```

There are also whitespaces and newlines all over the place. 
I need to get only '`<br/>123456<br/>78910`' skipping the span element.
When I run this xpath: '//p/text()' I get 3 matches: The first - a bunch of spaces and newlines, the second one with 123456 and the third one with 78910.
Is there any other way to skip the span element? Is it possible to somehow join the matches?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted nodes. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "to join the matches"?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to select every node after the `span` element:

```
/p/span/following-sibling::node()
```

If you want the text node children without the white space only text nodes:

```
/p/text()[normalize-space()]
```

Comment: /p/span/following-sibling::node()[normalize-space()] and /p/text()[normalize-space()] returned 2 matches, there is no match with just spaces now, but I need to join these two matches

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
/p/node()[not(self::span) and (not(self::text[not(normalize-space())]))]
```

This selects all nodes that a children of the top element `p` and that if they are text nodes they are not white-space only.

Comment: It gives me 5 matches - 3 with just whitespaces and two with text, but I need to join them in 1 match. Is that possible?

Comment: @Desecho: An XPath expression selects *nodes* -- it cannot make one node out of several, because XPath is a query language and doesn't modify the XML document.